# How to add text above polyline in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have 2 markers, I would like to draw a line between them, and have a text showing the distance above the line, just like in the web version of google maps.

[image: maps]

I've already found [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/DistanceDemoActivity.java) sample about drawing a line between 2 markers, but how do I add text above the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea would be to calculate the midpoint between the two markers using their lat and long coordinates and then put an infowindow with whatever information you want to show. Or something like the following could help: [**Link**](https://duncan99.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/google-maps-api-polylines-and-events/)

Comment: Good idea, but according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows), only 1 infowindow can be visible at a time, and it has to be bound to a marker. So I would have to use an invisible marker, and not use any other infowindows.

Comment: Or another idea would be custom overlays. Use texts as custom overlays on top of the lines. But I doubt that this is any easier to achieve. Unfortunately, for now, it seems that there's no supported method that attaches text to a polyline yet.

Comment: Meanwhile I've tried out the infowindow hack, and it is crazy slow. I need to update it on every drag event so it will be at the proper point, and even with just 1 textview it's really slow. ~1-2fps during drag(on galaxy tab GT-P5200).

Comment: Please let me know if you eventually get a way better solution. I've been looking for a better answer as well.

Comment: I'll probably stick with yours (with updating the infowindow position maybe on every 5th drag even only) :)

Answer (score 9):

I had a situation to show the distance between two markers above the polyline.

Below is what was my requirement:

[image]

I managed to do it in some other way and it is quite interesting way, this way you can customize it to achieve anything.

**Steps:**

1. Calculate the distance between the markers by using [Location.distanceBetween()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29) method.
2. Create a new `Layout XML` file and create whatever type of `UI` you want to show for your text. In my case it contained only one `TextView`.
3. Set the calculated distance in the `TextView`.
4. Convert the `XML Layout` to `Bitmap`.
5. Create a `BitmapDescriptor` from that `Bitmap` object.
6. Find out the midpoint between the desired markers and add **a custom marker by using the `BitmapDescriptor`** created in last step and you are done.

**Code:**

> To calculate distance between two markers

```
float[] distance1 = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(userMarker.getPosition().latitude, userMarker.getPosition().longitude, positionMarker.getPosition().latitude, positionMarker.getPosition().longitude, distance1);
```

> Create Bitmap from XML Layout file

```
LinearLayout distanceMarkerLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.distance_marker_layout, null);

distanceMarkerLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
distanceMarkerLayout.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
distanceMarkerLayout.layout(0, 0, distanceMarkerLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), distanceMarkerLayout.getMeasuredHeight()); 
distanceMarkerLayout.buildDrawingCache(true);

TextView positionDistance = (TextView) distanceMarkerLayout.findViewById(R.id.positionDistance);

positionDistance.setText(distance1[0]+" meters");           

Bitmap flagBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(distanceMarkerLayout.getDrawingCache());
                distanceMarkerLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                BitmapDescriptor flagBitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(flagBitmap);
```

> To find out mid point between two markers do something like the following:

```
double dLon = Math.toRadians(flagMarker.getPosition().longitude - positionMarker.getPosition().longitude);

double lat1 = Math.toRadians(positionMarker.getPosition().latitude);
double lat2 = Math.toRadians(flagMarker.getPosition().latitude);
double lon1 = Math.toRadians(positionMarker.getPosition().longitude);

double Bx = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);
double By = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(dLon);
double lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) + Math.sin(lat2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(lat1) + Bx) + By * By));
double lon3 = lon1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(lat1) + Bx);

lat3 = Math.toDegrees(lat3);
lon3 = Math.toDegrees(lon3);
```

> Add a new cutom marker by using the bitmap descriptor created by us in previous steps

```
Marker centerOneMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lat3, lon3))
                .icon(flagBitmapDescriptor));
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, you saved my day @gprathour, Thank you.

Comment: @AmitabhSarkar Welcome :)

Comment: How the hell did it occur to you?!You're a genius.

Comment: What's with all those calculation just use (lat1 + lat2)/2 and same for lon1 and lon2

Comment: @stevemoretz Thanks buddy! I just made out a way to do it at that time and wanted to share it so that it might help someone else also. Apart from it, as of now, I don't remember about the calculations and why those were required. If you got a better way of doing it, please feel free to share.

Comment: @gprathour maybe you wanted to get the heading angle but you forgot?My way is rather simple you use:    fun calculateMiddlePoint(a: LatLng, b: LatLng): LatLng =
        LatLng(((a.latitude + b.latitude) / 2), ((a.longitude + b.longitude) / 2))
and another function for calculating heading angle:    fun angleFromCoordinate(fLat : LatLng,sLat : LatLng): Float =(Math.atan2(sLat.longitude - fLat.longitude, sLat.latitude - fLat.latitude) * 180 / Math.PI).toFloat()
as you see they are only two lines of code :) feel free to update your answer with my code.(It's in kotlin btw)

Comment: The angle function gives you the heading you should do +90 or -90 to get the text aligned with the line.use MarkerOptions.rotation(...) For doing that I think you know that already anyway.But maybe it helps somebody else :)